# Why are constexpr functions possibly ill-formed, NDR (10.1.5)?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, constexpr, compile-time-constant, constant-expression

Paragraph 10.1.5 says that a program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if a function is declared `constexpr` but no set of arguments exist that make it evaluable at compile-time.

What's the rationale behind this?

Since it's not feasible for the compiler to check that precondition, how can it benefit from this rule?
However, the only alternative I would see is to declare such programs well-formed (and so barely enforcing `constexpr` at all, making it rather a kind of hint to the compiler and reader). But wouldn't this still be preferable to having more UB in C++, with all its undesirable consequences? Maybe `constexpr` is [indeed](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2043r0.pdf) going in the wrong direction...

Comment: There is similar rule about template, so it is consistent.

Comment: It is not feasible in general, but some cases can be diagnosed.